# Is it possible to include a file which is in my PC?

Tags: php, include

I am trying to do a little tricky thing to include a file in my index.php file so that when ever a user try to access that page it checks for the file test.txt in the user PCs (My documents) if it is there JUst ok.If the file is not there exit , dont let him show the login page(index.php).

this is what i am doing `include("C:/My Documents/test.txt")`.Is it possible by any other or this way?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it has no access to the client machine.

Comment: I would say in php no, because php is executing on your server and not in client browser...

Comment: This would be a huge security risk if it was possible. Think about it...

Comment: Got it i was thinking too silly about php :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-sided scripting language. `include( ... )` will search the file system on the server for the page to include. The client side is in 99.9% of the cases a totally different machine, and doesn't even need to exist to execute a php script. As far as I am aware, a webpage is not able to interact with the filesystem of the client, unless the user decides to upload a file and submit the form, or drag and drop a file into a specific area of the webpage (html5).

Cookies might be able to accomplish what you are searching for though.

Comment: can java script or any othr language can help me doing it

Comment: Or i have to go for an application on client side?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do with that file. It sounds like you want to identify a user (or computer) first before showing something, and I don't see why a unique cookie (e.g. php session cookie) and some server-sided checking wouldn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

No there's not unless using some sort of plug-in in the browser which has to be granted by the user...and for what purpose you need it ?

Comment: i want only the uthentic people to see the login page of my site

Comment: but if you provide login credentials (user name /password ) and based on that  people login then "Authentication" is maintain ..